# constructing graph using rdflib for the outputs from sparql 'SELECT' query with sparqlWrapper

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, rdflib, sparqlwrapper

I am trying to construct a graph out of the results from SPARQL query. For the purpose of the query construction, I'm using SparqlWrapper and DBpedia as the knowledge base.

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
from rdflib import Namespace, Graph, URIRef
from rdflib.namespace import RDF, FOAF
g = Graph()
name = "Asturias"
#labelName = URIRef("<http://dbpedia.org/resource/" + name +">")

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery("""
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX dbr:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
    SELECT *
    WHERE { dbr:Asturias ?predicate ?object }
""")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()

for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
        predicate = result["predicate"]["value"]
        object = result["object"]["value"]
        print(name , predicate , object)
        g.add((name, predicate, object))

print(len(g))
g.serialize(destination='./resources/testg.n3', format='n3')
```

This outputs

```
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing
```

and lot more results, but I'm looking for a way to construct a graph from the results, for it to be merged with existing graphs/'s.

This throws me an error as

```
in add
    "Predicate %s must be an rdflib term" % (p,)
AssertionError: Predicate http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type must be an rdflib term
```

The problem is the output JSON's value is something like this [Link](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbr%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0ASELECT%20*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%20dbr%3AAsturias%20%3Fpredicate%20%3Fobject%20%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)

Comment: The error message should be clear enough. You have to create the RDF terms out of the string values: https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rdf_terms.html and https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_creating_rdf.html

Comment: Indeed, the better option would be to use a SPARQL `CONSTRUCT` query which in fact returns a set of triples